# Handling reals in Fortran together with R

Tags: r, fortran

I am having trouble handling reals in Fortran, which I use together with R. The following code is written in Fortran:

```
Subroutine realtest(lol)
implicit none
Real lol
lol = 10.0
End
```

I compile with the command `R CMD SHLIB realtest.f`. If I run the shared object in R as:

```
dyn.load("realtest.so")
res <- .Fortran("realtest",lol= as.numeric(1.2))
```

The resulting value of `lol` is 1.2, but it should have been 10. If I do the whole thing with Integers instead, I get the correct value 10.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using `double precision` instead of `real`; the following works for me:

```
! realtest.f90
!
subroutine realtest(x)
    implicit none

    double precision, intent(inout) :: x
    x = 10.0
end subroutine realtest
```

From R,

```
dyn.load("realtest.so") 
res <- .Fortran("realtest", x = as.double(1.2))
res
# $x
# [1] 10
```

Answer (score -1):

You should declare `lol` as `real*8` since R uses double-precision floating-point number.

Comment: Please don't add any signatures and thanks and similar to your posts. Your name is already put under your posts automatically. Also note that `real*8` is not standard Fortran.